# How do Ethereum's transaction fees compare to Bitcoin?

Tags: fees, bitcoin

Ethereum has faster transactions than the 10 minutes of standard bitcoin protocol.
How do the transaction fees compare at the moment if you translate the price into a comparable currency like dollars or euros?
Long-term how are they likely to compare?

Comment: etherdelta is charging 58gwei ($6) per transaction right now... is that legit?

Answer (score 39):

Every computation on the Ethereum network cost *gas*, so do value transfers like on the bitcoin blockchain.

Every computational step, or OPCODE requires a specific amount of gas (which is hardcoded). You pay for gas using *ether*. To determine the fee you pay you calculate:

`required gas * gas price = fee`

For example a simple value transfer cost 21000 gas, the current gas price is dynamically set by users and miners and is currently ~0.00000005 ether, so the value transaction would cost **~0.00105 ether** or **$0.001 to $0.002 USD** at current prices. Current BTC transaction fees vary anywhere from **$0.01 to $0.09 USD**

Users can set the gas price they are willing to pay and and miners can set the minimum gas price they are willing to accept. This creates a dynamic market, which allows ethers "fee" to be dynamic and adopt to ether price swings.

Comment: I don't think this answer tells me whether I can expect the fees payed on ethereum to be higher or lower than in bitcoin when converted into dollars.

Answer (score 14):

In short, in Ethereum the fees are paid in gas and calculated based on contract code execution complexity, in bitcoin the're based solely on transaction size.

See the these Ethereum gas fees tables ( [table1](http://ether.fund/tool/gas-fees), [table2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit#gid=0) ) for the complete gas costs for executing contract code.

The fee for a value transfer is `21000 gas`, you need to check the current gas price on the [Ethereum Stats](https://stats.ethdev.com/) and then multiply the gas cost for the gas price or you can use this [gas calculator](http://ether.fund/tool/calculator) that also does unit conversion.

For Bitcoin you can check the [fees explanation page and formula](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees) from the bitcoin wiki.

This is the formula is:

```
priority = sum(input_value_in_base_units * input_age)/size_in_bytes
```

The recommended bitcoin standard transaction fee is 0.1mBTC (10000 satoshis) even if the minimum fee around ~0.055mBTC. 
The fees rises if you aggregate multiple inputs, to produce multiple outputs instead, because their size is smaller (1/4) compared to an input, the amount to pay is smaller.