# Are all constant methods free?

Tags: solidity

a Consensys factory class has this method:

//verifies if a contract that has been deployed is a Human Standard Token.
    //NOTE: This is a very expensive function, and should only be used in an eth_call. ~800k gas

```
function verifyHumanStandardToken(address _tokenContract) constant returns (bool) ...
```

Do certain constant methods use gas? Don't they just query the blockchain on the local node?

Can somebody clarifies this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what constant means.
A constant function means that your node does not need a transaction to run it - because it does not alter any state. However, if your constant function is called within a transaction - it will cost gas as part of a transaction.
What you could do with constant code is running it outside (e.g. before) a transaction on your node. Then it will not cost any gas.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Edmund's](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13855/425) answer on this topic.

Constant functions can be run by **your** node for free.

If however you want them to be run as **part of** a transaction, they need to be run on chain (which costs gas). This is because Ethereum is a **trustless** ledger. If it were not run on chain, the result could be tampered with.

Comment: Check the contract: https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/HumanStandardTokenFactory.sol line 19, as you can see, the function is intended to be called independently. In such case, should cost anything right? I guess my real question is, under which case you would call this method in chain transaction? why?

Answer (score 0):

A constant function is expected to keep the state of the contract constant. There should be no point (although permitted) in sending a transaction to the contract to execute a constant function.