# Using "sendTransaction" when we call a contract function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation

I've seen some contracts like [here](https://github.com/stonecoldpat/anonymousvoting/blob/master/Web3/vote.html) (e.g. in line 332), use "sendTransaction" when they call contract's function. Cannot we call a function without using "sendTransaction"? As I've been calling functions without using it (on testrpc and private chain) and it works fine.

**Question** 1: Do we have to use "sendTransaction" when we call a contract function?

**Question** 2:  When should we use "sendTransaction"?

Comment: [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/could-we-call-a-constant-function-without-spending-any-gas-inside-a-transaction) question may help you.

Comment: It should not be necessary for a non consant function `contract.method(params)`  is equivalente to `contract.method.sendTransaction(params)`. And for a constant function `contract.method(params)` is equivalente to `contract.method.callparams)`. I remember some version failed to recognize properly a function as constant so I've to force `contract.method.call(params)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can interact with smart contract depending on what you want to accomplish. Here you can find detailed explanation on what does what [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call?newreg=fa9e4b13de434ad39fe0e63f191da0db)