# Transaction not being recorded

Tags: web3js, transactions, truffle, gas, testrpc

I'm writing a snippet of code that should call an API and record the response to the chain:

```
function(APIResponse) {
    // Write to chain
    console.log(`API responded with:\n${APIResponse}`);
    let callResult = instance.writeResponse.call(APIResponse);
    console.log(`Writing api response to chain result: ${callResult}`);
    const ID = instance.writeResponse.sendTransaction(APIResponse);
    console.log(`Transaction ID: ${ID}`)
}
```

In an attempt to use the proper pattern, I first call to check the function and later send the transaction. The *call* passes and returns a boolean value, but the *sendTransaction* fails with the following:

```
requestmanager.js:61 Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas(…)
```

Referencing a similar [issue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/who-gets-the-fee-from-contract-call/10923#10923) I attempted to add gas to the function calls:

```
function(APIResponse) {
    // Write to chain
    console.log(`API responded with:\n${APIResponse}`);
    let callResult = instance.writeResponse.call({gas: helper.averageGasBump}, APIResponse);
    console.log(`Writing api response to chain result: ${callResult}`);
    const ID = instance.writeResponse.sendTransaction({gas: helper.averageGasBump}, APIResponse);
    console.log(`Transaction ID: ${ID}`)
}
```

This time, no Error is thrown, the transaction gets recorded but when I try to access the varable that should have been stored in the chain as a JSON string, an empty string is being returned.

Interestingly enough, inside truffle console I can invoke all functions without the need for an additional gas bump and they get recorded properly.

I'm using *testrpc*.

Could you explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found out where the problem was - I was missusing the API.

The propper call with the gas bump should have been:

```
instance.writeResponse.call(APIResponse, {gas: helper.averageGasBump});
```