# Can a contract function both change the state and return a value when it's called externally

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

Assume we have a test() function in our contract:

```
contract {
 uint state;

 function test() returns (bool ){
   state= 5;
   return true; 
 }
}
```

I'm aware that if the test() function didn't have to change the state, then we can use:

```
  ver result= instance. test.call();
```

where "instance" is an instance of deployed contract. But what about the above case? The above code can be used in a case where a user interface  interactively tells users that their request has been completed (e.g. their vote has been registered, etc.)

Comment: You cannot get the return value of a function executed by a transaction. The workaround is to generate an event with the actual result. Events are recorded in the transaction receipt and can be recovered by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use call() on constant functions. It seems the constant keywork is [not yet implemented](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#constant-state-variables) inside the EVM:

```
The compiler does not enforce yet that a view method is not modifying state.
```

However, call() doesn't work the same in and out of the EVM, you can read a [more in-depth explanation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10923/14311). An outside call, from web3js for example, will run locally and state changes won't be propagated.

I'm not sure of your exact question, but if you modify anything inside a call() your changes will be lost.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me what the solution is?

Comment: The the 2 other comments. What are you trying to do actually? What is the problem? Are you trying to get a result from the function? Are you trying to determine whether you can use call() or not?