# Using events and logs to get function returned value with a simple example

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation, events, logs

My question is related to this one:

[Can a contract function both change the state and return a value when it's called externally](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26903/can-a-contract-function-both-change-the-state-and-return-a-value-when-its-calle)

---

**Question**: How to read event/log content?

I have a contract like:

```
contract  Aa {

 uint state;
 event CheckVal(bool value);
 function test() returns (bool ){

 bool temp=true;
 CheckVal(temp);
 state= 5;
 return temp; 
 }
}
```

I want to both change the state and get the returned value: "temp". I'm following the guide from [here](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e) (the 1st usecase).

The problem is that when in my geth console, I put

```
  exampleEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
 if (err) {
 console.log(err)
 return;
  }
 console.log(result.args.temp)   
 })
```

only three dots will appear(i.e. ...), so I cannot get the value I want and I cannot send a transaction to the private chain and see the returned value:

```
instance.test.sendTranaction({gass:4200000});
```

I'm wondering how I can get the return value in geth console.

Comment: throw in some semicolons after console.log arguments and give it another try.  for me , the ... usually means somethings not closed (a parentheses, function, etc)

Comment: @thefett thanks, I've followed your suggestion and the problem has been solved. But I still don't know how to get the result value, if I call console.log(); only  "undefined" would pop up, but I want to see the value of "temp".

Comment: So it will be undefined until it mines.  I think this post may help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-function-with-argument-is-called?rq=1